# Div seemingly enclosing other parts of the page

Tags: css, html

Why does the rest of the content get the footer's background? Chrome says everything on the page is part of the footer div... wtf am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"

content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<style type="text/css">
html,body{margin:0;padding:0}
body{font: 76% arial,sans-serif;text-align:center}
p{margin:0 10px 10px}
a{display:block;color: #981793;padding:10px}
div#header h1{height:80px;line-height:80px;margin:0;
  padding-left:10px;background: #EEE;color: #79B30B}
div#container{text-align:left}
div#content p{line-height:1.4}
div#navigation{background:#B9CAFF}
div#extra{background:#FF8539}
div#footer{background: #333;color: #FFF}
div#footer p{margin:0;padding:5px 10px}

div#container{width:700px;margin:0 auto}
div#content{float:right;width:500px}
div#navigation{float:left;width:200px}
div#extra{clear:both;width:100%}
</style>

<title>Kockums</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="header">

<table>

<tr>

<td><a href="http://intranet/">INTRAN&Auml;T</a></td>

<td><a href="http://www.google.com/">INTERNET</a></td>

<td><a href="index.php">RITNINGSARKIV</a></td>

</tr>

</table>

</div>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="navigation">


<div class="menu">

<a href="?page=add_drawing "title="L&auml;gg till en ny ritning"

class="menu">L&auml;gg till ritning</a>

</div>

</div>

<div id="content">



<div class="text">

<form id="signin" name="signin" action="index.php" method="post">

<fieldset class="signin">

<legend>Logga in</legend>

<table width="250">

<tr>

<td width="120"><label for="username">Anv&auml;ndarnamn:</label></td>



<td width="130" align="right"><input type="text" name="username" id="username"

size="15" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Logga in" /></td>

</tr>

</table>

</fieldset>

</form>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

<table width="100%">

<tr>

<td class="text">Footer goes here</td>

</tr>

</table>

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the footer style with:

```
div#footer{
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and add the style:

```
div#wrapper{
    float:left;
}
```

**Why?**

As for the why, I'm not completely sure what the underlying w3c standard is but I know how to work with it :)

When you inspect your wrapper (Inspect Element in chrome) you can see that it has no height. The Footer then sits right underneath your header and inline's the content of both your wrapper and footer with the footer div as the background. By floating your elements and giving them a width they now become block's in themselves and will float. Since there is not enough room to float horizontally they'll be placed underneath eachother.

Comment: Thanks! So what was the problem then? The footer being behind the rest of the page?

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you and added a little "why?" description

Answer (score 0):

You had a DIV tag mismatch I believe. The other answer may visually fix the problem, but the bad HTML will still remain. DIV based layouts blow up when you forget to close a tag.  I used HTML Tidy to fix it:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://intranet/">INTRANÄT</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://www.google.com/">INTERNET</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="index.php">RITNINGSARKIV</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="?page=add_drawing" title="Lägg till en ny ritning" class="menu">Lägg till ritning</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="text">
                <form id="signin" name="signin" action="index.php" method="post">
                    <fieldset class="signin">
                        <legend>Logga in</legend>
                        <table width="250">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="120">
                                    <label for="username">Användarnamn:</label>
                                </td>
                                <td width="130" align="right">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="15" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Logga in" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="text">
                    Footer goes here
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```